# Express and Nodejs : Best way to call an external API

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I am new to Express and Nodejs. I am trying to call an external api for building data on a page. Is there a way to call the external api from express itself (I know i can use http moduel to do this) but want to confirm is that the best way. Also once i get the json back how do i pass it to the view.

Right now i have done a workaround by just loading the view(just headers) with express and making an jquery  ajax call to api and populate the data.

Comment: What API? Some APIs have specific libraries build for Node that you could use to connect to the service. Often you can just Google "$API Node API".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you need to call your external API inside controller where you want to populate it. The best will be to use `http` module, it is pretty easy to use http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.10/api/http.html#http.get . After you get data, you just pass it to view like this:

```
http.get(options, function(data) {
    res.render('template', data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks , but what if i want to recursively call the external Api to populate the list . Should i create a library and use it to call recursively. I will then have to merge all the data responses to come up with the final response?

Comment: what if one of the request fails or return corrupted data, will i get the resposne with the others?

Comment: @SaNmm with `async.map()` you apply same function for each url in your array. You will form your final result by yourself

Comment: yes i have done that and it work when the request returns json , but if any one of the request fails/or returns errored data the entire async call fails with error. Is there a way just to ingonre one request and commence with other responses

Answer (score 1):

I would write an object to hide the details of this data fetching (http requests) and make the http calls using [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) (just because it's a nice lib).

This way you can:

- Replace the http requests later if you decide to use something else.
- Hide details like using the [node-async](https://github.com/caolan/async) as monkeyinsight suggested.