# API using nodejs express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web

I have to build an API for weather application using express node.js. since I am not saving any data, I am not using the database. my application allows the user to enter a city name, and the weather information will retrieve directly from the openweathermap.org

the question is, I have a working javascript application, but how to GET the weather data from openweathermap.org in the API route city/:cityName

Comment: You're looking for something like https://github.com/request/request

Comment: Please be more specific about your problem. What makes you incapable of requesting data from that service, and in what circumstances? Can you show some of your code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Express and Nodejs : Best way to call an external API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329574/express-and-nodejs-best-way-to-call-an-external-api)

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, I would suggest using the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) library. Read up on their documentation on how to process a GET request.

You should also refer to the [openwathermap API](http://openweathermap.org/appid) protocol to see how they expect requests. Also as a side not I would suggest referencing citys by ID, not name.